Formalist or Platonist--does it make any difference in mathematical practice?
Can a formalist obtain results in, say, real analysis that a Platonist cannot or vice versa?

No, because both use Classical Logic.

It is not a question of "cannot", that is not what mathematical practice is about. Platonists and formalists have different kinds of intuitions and motivations, so the types of results they tend to pursue may differ. Or they may pursue the same results in different ways. But one can, in principle, obtain results of the other and certainly can follow the other's proofs of them.

@Conifold So, is it just a matter of personal preference in one's narrative style?

It may be a deeper and more interesting question to swirl your question, that is, does difference in mathematical practice make the practitioner to form different philosophy of mathematics? The practice of whomever is obviously the means at least colloquially speaking, and the mature philosophizing thereof shall be the ends...

It is neither personal nor a preference, mathematicians can do little to 'prefer' their 'style', and it is not about a narrative. Their dispositions and experience structure their thinking in certain ways, which fall into some common patterns. The narrative comes after the results they are led to are worked out and there they have more room to exercise preferences.

Platonism and formalism are not the only approaches to the philosophy of mathematics. While different approaches do not result in different practices in most subjects, they can lead to differences. For example, intuitionists have a different standard of what counts as a mathematical proof and they reject non-constructive proofs. ¬(∀x)Fx does not entail (∃x)¬Fx intuitionistically. Some approaches to the philosophy of mathematics might lead to rejecting transfinite set theory or to rejecting infinitessimals.

@Bumble IIUC intuitionist logic is just a working subset of classical logic. It simply disallows certain axioms of classical logic that, for reasons I don't understand, are found to be somehow suspect. Every proof based on intuitionist logic is also a proof in classical logic, is it not?

@DanChristensen - Intuitionism is more than that. The intuitionist view of the continuum is also pretty different from the classical one. Cantor's continuum hypothesis has no immediate meaning, for instance. Also, to describe intuitionist logic as "just a subset" fails to do justice to the fact that in intuitionism mathematical theorems may mean something different.

@DanChristensen - The way continuity/continuous functions is seen is also pretty different and not completely compatible. A focus on logic hides these aspects. Besides, logic has no foundational role in the intuitionist's view.

@DanChristiansen It is correct to say that intuitionistic proofs are all classically valid, but not the other way round. Consequently, some theorems of classical mathematics are not theorems of intuitionistic mathematics, so there is a difference in practice. Intuitionists are not platonists: they regard mathematical truths as products of rational intuition, not as statements about an abstract reality. As mudskipper says, it leads to a rather different understanding of mathematics.

@DanChristensen - I'm tempted to write an answer, but your question seems ambiguous to me: Is it a question about the process of discovery (=solving unsolved mathematical problems) or a question about the process of proving (=rigorously verifying a discovery and establishing that it is true)? Those are two pretty different perspectives.

@mudskipper The latter. The public part of mathematics. That which is published or otherwise presented to some audience.

To pick up on user Bumble's comment on infinitesimals, I would point out that there would indeed be practical differences between a Formalist and a Platonist, as determined by their respective philosophical positions.
Consider, for example, the mathematical entity R (the real number line).  A Platonist believes that he has a detailed grasp of the latter that accounts for the type of elements R may contain and its further properties.  Similar remarks apply to "the" natural numbers N.
A Formalist considers an infinitary entity like R necessarily reference-less (either in the physical realm or any putative Platonic realm), and refrains from asserting that he possesses a detailed grasp of R, which to him is only a theory (since a Formalist would reject the notion of a standard model a.k.a. Intended Interpretation of an entity like R).
How do such views play out in practice?  Consider, for example, the axiomatic theories of nonstandard analysis (NSA), as developed by Karel Hrbacek and Edward Nelson (independently) in the 1970s, about a decade after Robinson's original work on NSA.  In the axiomatic approaches, infinitesimals are found within R itself (rather than in an extension, as in the model-theoretic approaches to NSA), and nonstandard numbers in N itself (rather than an extension); see this introduction.
A Formalist would likely take this in stride.  After all, she never claimed to possess a detailed grasp of each and every element of R (or of N); that there turn out to be elements she has not noticed before is an interesting idea.
A Platonist is as likely as not to shrink away in horror: "What, the categorical and unique R that I knew and loved for so many years, all of a sudden contains things I never dreamed of?"  It is clear that it will be harder for him to work in such a framework or to accept its legitimacy.

A bit of a tangent, but: What you mentioned about Hrbacek and Nelson axiomatization which has infinitesimals “hiding” (so to speak) within R sounds fascinating. Wondering if you know of resource(s) (book, paper, etc.) that you would recommend as a good introduction to this topic.

@NikS, I added a link in my answer.

Indeed a Platonist is as likely as not to shrink away in horror, since Hrbacek & Nelson works in internal set theory (IST) with different axioms from ZFC and IST axioms already internalize many nonstandard or ilimit entities at the proof-theoretic level, so there's no surprise at all infinitesimals will hide in the Platonically intended standard R...

@DoubleKnot, just to be sure we agree about the facts.  (1) Nelson's IST incorporates all the axioms of ZFC (and adds three axioms to govern the interaction of the new predicate with the axioms of ZFC); (2) IST is conservative over ZFC; this means not merely that it is consistent if and only if ZFC is consistent, but that IST (in theory) proves exactly the same statements as ZFC (so long as the statements don't involve the new predicate).  Are you with me so far?

Indeed IST conservatively extends ZFC results that don't involve the st predicate. It essentially wraps ZFC to handle infinitesimals and other nonstandard elements without altering the standard mathematical universe structure as understood by ZFC. With the added 3 axioms, idealization and transfer principle stipulate and internalize infinitesimals and infinities into R and N for every IST's possible model which is nonstandard via the choice of different ultrafilters same as NSA, and standardization standardizes them, yet ZFC's nonstandard models implicitly follow transfer and idealization...

It recently turned out that ultrafilters are unncessary here, and in fact infinitesimals in nonstandard analysis can be practiced conservatively over ZF (rather than ZFC).  See the introduction linked in my answer.  @DoubleKnot

I've seen. Even if no need of ultrafilter in SPOT, Transfer and Nontriviality alone enforce its nonstandard models, SPOT as a subtheory of IST is still non-categorical, meaning there're still many possible different nonstandard models albeit each one has infinitesimals and infinities along with shadows. OTOH all ZF's possible models including nonstandard ones also implicitly follow Transfer and Nontriviality without explicit axiomatization. Since one cannot pin down a categorical model of SPOT, I'm not clear what's real advantage here? Also why ringinal is not just the first limit ordinal?...

@DoubleKnot, notice that your argument rests on a philosophical assumption, namely that of the existence of a "standard model" (a.k.a. intended interpretation).  One cannot derive mathematical conclusions from a philosophical assumption.  In particular, the R of SPOT is as categorical as R is reputed to be.  With regard to your philosophical assumption, note that some mathematicians don't subscribe to it; see e.g., the quotation from Robinson here.

Since intentionality is the mark of consciousness, intended model or element is unavoidable, even IST has to introduce the intended st predicate to some elements in the domain. And since IST cannot prove its own consistency, like ZFC, any ‘unintended’ nonstandard model of IST is intended to exist but not ensured by IST from within, otherwise its consistency is immediate. So there’s still some implicitly intended meta-theory implies its consistency, assuming it’s consistent…

I certainly agree that Goedel incompleteness applies to IST just as it applies to ZFC, PA, etc.  But I am not sure what you are trying to say.  @DoubleKnot

My intention is current ZFC/NSA is quite flexible so that applied mathematicians can intend about the standard model for applications while pure mathematicians can use any extended nonstandard model from their choose of ultrapower construction for their intended classical or Cartanian exterior differential form infinitesimal use. SPOT with each of its model being nonstandard axiomatically enforced by syntax, applied mathematicians are forced to face nonstandard elements with their really intended shadows...

@Double, applied mathematicians aren't forced to do anything by SPOT. They can continue working as if nothing happened so long as they don't use the new predicate (even if all around them adopt SPOT, which is not going to happen tomorrow). Should they want to define the continuity of a specific f at a specific c, they can say "infinitesimal increment alpha will always produce an infinitesimal change f(c+alpha)-f(c) in the function", as Cauchy did 200 years ago. Similar simplifications exist for defining integral via infinitesimal partitions and other subjects; see our recent series of papers.
